# No stacktrace in Android 8.0 for netty initChannel

Tags: android, ssl, netty

I have coded setup of a client ssl call using a keystore with a private key (and certificate) for the authentication of the client to the server and a cert (really certs) to authenticate the server to the client. The problem is that i get a system err upon this line of code:

```
            b.connect().sync().channel();
```

The code (content of initChannel):

```
    SslContextBuilder sslBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();
                    SslContext cont2 = null;
                    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    // truststore
                    KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                    clientKeyStore.load(null, SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
                    for (Cert clientCertCert : sipSettingsBean.getSipSettingsServerBeans().get(0).getCerts()) {
                        Certificate clientCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                                .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                        clientCertCert.getCert().getBytes()));
                        clientKeyStore.setCertificateEntry(
                                clientCertCert.getAlias(), clientCert);
                    }

                    trustManagerFactory.init(clientKeyStore);
                    sslBuilder.trustManager(trustManagerFactory);
                    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
                            .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                    KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                    serverKeyStore.load(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    sipSettingsBean.getSipSettingsServerBeans().get(0).getKeystore().getBytes()),
                            SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
                    if (!serverKeyStore.isKeyEntry(sipSettingsBean.getSipSettingsServerBeans().get(0).getKeystoreAlias()))
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "Keystore file has no matching key for given alias.");
                    keyManagerFactory.init(serverKeyStore,
                            SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
                    sslBuilder.keyManager(keyManagerFactory);
                    cont2 = sslBuilder.build();
                    SSLEngine engine = cont2.newEngine(ch.alloc(), toHostname,
                            portDestination);
                    engine.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine, false));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("handler",
                            simpleChannelInboundHandlerRegisterTCP);
```

Log Output:

```
System.err:07-19 22:30:16.437 7609-7638/xx.xxxxxxx.sipclient W/System.err: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException07-19 22:30:16.437 7609-7638/xx.xxxxxxx.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(...)(Unknown Source)
```

Is there anything anyone can see immediately that should be different?

I am using netty 4.1.20.Final
Tried netty 4.1.22.Final also.
Tried netty 4.1.28.Final also.
Android 8.0

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace, not the log print?

Comment: Seems the problem is that inside initChannel (which throws Exception) no printout is done. When try-cathing the contents - or moving/copying that code out of the initChannel you are able to see the stacktrace. Doing this in Android resulted in seeing that JKS type Keystores are not allowed in Android, only BKS (Bouncycastle) thus allowing me to solve the problem.

Comment: I have received some bad for this input. I am sorry if this is not the proper way to address my problem. No stacktrace was output in Android Studio 3.01 and I just wondered if anyone else also had seen the same and found a way out of it. Again, sorry for any inconvenience and I will try to be more informative next time I post.

Answer (score 1):

Seems for Android the problem is that inside initChannel (which throws Exception) no printout is done. When try-cathing the contents - or moving/copying that code out of the initChannel you are able to see the stacktrace. Doing this in Android resulted in seeing that JKS type Keystores are not allowed in Android, only BKS (Bouncycastle) thus allowing me to solve the problem. The problem does not appear other than in Android.